# bootstrap-select auto scroll on ie10, 11 and ie8

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have used Bootstrap select, In that drop down contain country, states list. When i select country then states drop down html refress

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: base_url + "UserBusinesses/ajaxState/" + countryId,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#UserBusinessStateId').html('<option value="">Loding... </option>');
            $('#UserBusinessStateId').selectpicker('refresh');
            $('#UserBusinessCityId').html('<option value="">Select city</option>');
            $('#UserBusinessCityId').selectpicker('refresh');
        },
        success: function (obj) {
            var addHtml = '';
            addHtml += '<option value="">Select state</option>';
            $.each(obj, function (key, value) {
                var selected = "";
                if (selectedState == key) {
                    var selected = "selected='selected'";
                }
                addHtml += "<option value='" + key + "' " + selected + ">" + value + "</option>";
            });
            jQuery("#UserBusinessStateId").html(addHtml);

            $('#UserBusinessStateId').selectpicker('refresh');

        }
    });
```

It working fine in other browser but in ie when we select state drop down then scroller automatically working mean's it's go down. How can i solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. It seems that this happens when populating the drop down options automatically. I found a workaround, which is to define the first option explicitly in the html file, ie add a line `<option value='yourvalue'>youroption </option>` between the `<select>` tags. Then you can populate the rest of the options in `js` (and if needed overwrite that first option specified in the html file). That did the trick for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28879182/bootstrap-select-drop-list-moves-down-ward-automatically/28983963#28983963 check this